# UserSession authenticity token is being shared across different users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server, passenger

I am using rails 4.0.3 with [passenger](https://github.com/phusion/passenger) and [authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) to build a web app and am running into a problem when a user logs in, but is using a previous users authenticity token when creating a new UserSession. Has anyone experienced anything like this regarding sessions? This results in user 2 being logged in under user 1's session and having incorrect access rights.

User 1 login request:

```
I, [2017-12-14T15:08:11.566277 #25162]  INFO -- : Started POST "/login" for 172.68.xxx.xxx at 2017-12-14 15:08:11 +0000
I, [2017-12-14T15:08:11.567479 #25162]  INFO -- : Processing by UserSessionsController#create as HTML
I, [2017-12-14T15:08:11.567545 #25162]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4FgeuK825Mw4wfKvnHv1CXg3t5sNV1P621fdsgXzplE=", "user_session"=>{"email"=>"user1@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign In"}
```

User login request 2:

```
I, [2017-12-14T15:08:49.905291 #25162]  INFO -- : Started POST "/login" for 172.68.xxx.xxx at 2017-12-14 15:08:49 +0000
I, [2017-12-14T15:08:49.906435 #25162]  INFO -- : Processing by UserSessionsController#create as HTML
I, [2017-12-14T15:08:49.906494 #25162]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4FgeuK825Mw4wfKvnHv1CXg3t5sNV1P621fdsgXzplE=", "user_session"=>{"email"=>"user2@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign In"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to override ActionController::Base#handle_unverified_request to make sure to destroy it.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :current_user_session, :current_user

  private
    def current_user_session
      return @current_user_session if defined?(@current_user_session)
      @current_user_session = UserSession.find
    end

    def current_user
      return @current_user if defined?(@current_user)
      @current_user = current_user_session && current_user_session.user
    end

  protected
    def handle_unverified_request
      # destroy session, redirect
      if current_user_session
        current_user_session.destroy
      end
      redirect_to root_url
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I just applied the handle_unverified_request as you mentioned. I'm going to do some testing over night to see if I'm still seeing any duplicate authenticity tokens and report back with if the problem was resolved.

Comment: Following up after a weekend of bug free user sessions. Thanks for the help. I also upgraded the authlogic gem and noticed that a thread safe dependency got upgraded as well. Just speculating, but maybe that was part of the issue since I was only experiencing shared tokens during times when the server was heavily loaded.